# Maximal and minimal value of a function $4x^2-4xy+y^2$ at the border $x^2+y^2=25$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, quadratics

So my first thought was to find the critical points of the $4x^2-4xy+y^2$ and I calculated.
$$F_{x}=8x-4y,\quad F_{y}=2y-4x$$
and I found out that critical point are satisfying $x=2y$.

Then I put then to equation $x^2+y^2=25$.
And I calculated that $x=\sqrt5,y=2\sqrt5$, and $x=-\sqrt5$, $y=-2\sqrt5$.

But I don't know if they are maximum or minimum.

My last idea was to to put $x^2=25-y^2 $ to the function $4x^2-4xy+y^2$ and then calculate the derivative. But I do not know if it is a good solution.

Comment: have you tried using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: No, i dont really know how to do this using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Please distinguish between functions and equations.  $4x^2-4xy+y^2$ is a function, not an equation as you call it at the end.  $4x^2-4xy+y^2=2x$ is an equation.  You don't find critical points of an equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's obvious that the minimum is $0$.

For $x=2\sqrt5$ and $y=-\sqrt5$ we get a value $125$.

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$(2x-y)^2\leq5(x^2+y^2)$$ or
$$(x+2y)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: I don't really think i can obtain a point which gives me the value of 0 and satisfy the $x^2+y^2=25$ at the same time.

Comment: Plug $y=2x$ into $x^2 + y^2 = 5^2$  Then $5x^2  = 5^2, x = \sqrt 5, y = 2\sqrt 5$ and $4x^2 - 4xy + y^2 = 20 - 40 + 20 = 0$

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that $F(x,y)=4x^2-4xy+y^2=(2x-y)^2\geq 0$.

Note that the level curves are the lines parallel to $y=2x$. 
Therefore the minimal value is $0$ and it is attained at the intersections of line $y=2x$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=5^2$.

On the other hand, the maximum value is attained when the level curve is tangent to the circle that is along the line $y=-x/2$ (which is orthogonal to $y=2x$).

Comment: I understand the first hint so for this values $x=\sqrt5,y=2\sqrt5$, and $x=-\sqrt5$, $y=-2\sqrt5$ i get 0 so i can say that they are minimal.But
"The maximum value is attained when the level curve is tangent to the circle that is along the line y=−x/2." I don't understand why.

Comment: @roffensive Draw the circle and the level curves. At each point of tangency, the tangent is orthogonal to the radius. You can also use $x=5\cos(t)$ and $y=5\sin(t)$ and consider the one-variable function $t\to F(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Using $F_x$ and $F_y$ as you have done is not going to help you complete the problem. Because along the constraint curve there can be extrema where $F_x$ and $F_y$ are nonzero.

In the comments, you said you do not know the method of Lagrange multipliers. So instead, try this. The points along the constraint curve are actually points on a circle $(5\cos(t),5\sin(t))$. So sub in $x=5\cos(t)$ and $y=5\sin(t)$ into your formula for $F$, and then analyze it as a one-variable function of $t$. When you find critical $t$-values, substitute them back to find the corresponding $x$ and $y$.

Comment: $100cos^2t - 20costsint+25sin^2t$ will it be something like this?

Comment: @roffensive Not quite: $100\cos^2(t)-100\cos(t)\sin(t)+25\sin^2(t)$. And that simplifies to $25+75\cos^2(t)-100\cos(t)\sin(t)$. Some useful trig indentities simplify that to $25+\frac{75}{2}+\frac{75}{2}\cos(2t)-50\sin(2t)$. And then $F'(t)=-75\sin(2t)-100\cos(2t)$. And you can analyze where this equals $0$ for $t$ in $[0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 0):

$x =u + 2v\\
y = 2u - v$

$4x^2 -4xy + y^2 = 4(u^2 + 4uv + 4v^2) - 4(2u^2 -3uv - 2v^2) + (4u^2 - 4uv + v^2) = 25 v^2$

$x^2 + y^2 = (u^2 + 4uv + 4v^2) + (4u^2 - 4uv + v^2) = 5u^2 + 5v^2 = 25$

Minimize $25v^2$ constrained by: $5u^2 + 5v^2 = 25$

$v = 0, u = \pm \sqrt 5\\
(x,y) = (\sqrt 5,2\sqrt 5), (-\sqrt 5, -2\sqrt5)$

Maximize $25v^2$ constrained by: $5u^2 + 5v^2 = 25$

$v = \pm \sqrt 5, u=  0\\
(x,y) = (2\sqrt 5, -\sqrt 5), (-2\sqrt 5, \sqrt 5)\\
4x^2 -4xy +y^2 = 125$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way is a bit simpler: by Weierstrass theorem, that functions attains a global maximum and a global minimum in the compact $x^2+y^2=25$. So you might as well just compare the images of those two points; the greater will be the maximum, and the lesser will be the minimum.